# Keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard

I have an LG r400 laptop and I just updated my OS to Ubuntu 13.10, but I cant use my keyboard since I started installing the new OS so I had to use the on board keyboard to complete the installation.

After the installation was done, the on board keyboard appeared automatically.

I have tried to change the keyboard input method system, but nothing worked out. Any idea on how to solve this?

PS: if I plug a keyboard using a usb port it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go to system settings,then keybord settings and add keyboard language. I had the same problem about a day ago while installing ubuntu on my old lap-top. It worked just fine when I added keyboard language.

Comment: Thank you @Aleksander i just tried it but also didn't work i think its a driver problem .because its recognizing my keyboard as a full keyboard not like the one i have (compact laptop type without the number section on the right side). any idea for a solution ?